# Parsing multiple XML files into one or more Object-classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsxmlparser

My app is made up of a TabBarController, each tab with a UITableView.

On launch I parse an XML file from my server into an Object class and then display the objects in the first tableview.

My question is, what do I do when I want to parse a second XML file? Currently, when doing so, the information in "XML-file-2" will overwrite the objects parsed by "XML-file-1". How do I go about this properly? Do I set up another Object class for each XML file or is there another to work around the issue?

I am using NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider having two instances of `XMLParser`, one for each XML file you want to read.  It allows you to read as many `XML` files concurrently without affecting each other.  It is also more modular.

Comment: That's what my initial thought was for the best approach to solving the issue; setting up several Object classes to hold the objects from each XML I parse and then each have XML to parse the file.

Comment: By the way. I ended up making a XMLParser super class and then divided the XML-file-specifics code in the XMLParser-subclasses. Works great.

Also, I made sure to do a performSelectorInBackground so it parses in the background and doesn't feel like it's stuck between the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

on line 21 of that snippet ( http://pastie.org/537227 ) you are setting the products array (`appDelegate.products`)to a new mutable array.  if you want the second run to append to `appDelegate.products,` you should see if `appDelegate.products` already has objects in it, if so, don't assign a new array to it, just add to them to it using NSMutableArray's addObject: method

Answer (score 0):

... Don't overwrite the data that's already there...?

If you're displaying the contents in a UITableView, then I'd be willing to bet you've got an NSArray in there somewhere.  Hopefully, if you've set this up properly, the NSArray contains model objects, each one of which corresponds to one row in your UITableView.  However, I would suggest using NSMutableArray.  Then when you parse the second XML file and build your model objects out of that, just use NSMutableArray's addObject: method and then reloadData on the UITableView.

Comment: Here's a code snippet from Parser.m file:

http://pastie.org/537227

Any comments welcome...

Comment: @Canada Dev - it looks OK to me.  Is it not working? When you create the NSXMLParser are you remembering to set this XMLParser object as the delegate?

Comment: Yeah, everything should be set correctly in my AppDelegate: http://pastie.org/538494

Answer (score 0):

As notnoop already mentioned, to make multiple NSXMLParser instances would be the best solution.
A open source iPhone RSS reader called [Simple RSS Reader](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-simple-rss-aggregator/) would be a good sample of what you want now.
You might use [RSSParser](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-simple-rss-aggregator/source/browse/trunk/Simple%20RSS/Classes/RssParser.m) class of the Simple RSS Reader as it is.

HTH